# Trying to receive a vector with MPI_Recv

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi

I'm implementing the Chan and Dehne sorting algorithm using MPI and the CGM realistic parallel model. So far each process receives N/p numbers from the original vector, each process then order their numbers sequentially using quick sort, each process then creates a sample from it's local vector (the sample has size p), each process then sends their sample over to P0; P0 should receive all samples in a bigger vector of size p*p so it can accommodate data from all processors. This is where I'm stuck, it seems to be working but for some reason after P0 receives all the data it exits with Signal: Segmentation fault (11). Thank you.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
// Step 2. Each process calculates it's local sample with size comm_sz
        local_sample = create_local_sample(sub_vec, n_over_p, comm_sz);

// Step 3. Each process sends it's local sample to P0
        if (my_rank == 0) {
            global_sample_receiver = (int*)malloc(pow(comm_sz,2)*sizeof(int));
            global_sample_receiver = local_sample;
            for (i = 1; i < comm_sz; i++) {
                MPI_Recv(global_sample_receiver+(i*comm_sz), comm_sz, MPI_INT,
                i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            }   
        } else {
            MPI_Send(local_sample, comm_sz, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        printf("P%d got here\n", my_rank);

        MPI_Finalize();
```

What is funny is that every process reachs the command `printf("P%d got here\n", my_rank);` and therefor prints to the terminal. Also `global_sample_receiver` does contain the data it is supposed to contain at the end, but the program still finished with a segmentation fault.

Here is the output:

```
P2 got here
P0 got here
P3 got here
P1 got here
[Krabbe-Ubuntu:05969] *** Process received signal ***
[Krabbe-Ubuntu:05969] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[Krabbe-Ubuntu:05969] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[Krabbe-Ubuntu:05969] Failing at address: 0x18000003e7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that process rank 0 with PID 5969 on node Krabbe-Ubuntu 
exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Edit: I found the problem, turns out local_sample also needed a malloc.

Comment: Can you post an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I will try onde I get home

Comment: Why do you `malloc` ` global_sample_receiver` and then overwrite it the line after ?

Comment: The purpose there is not to overwrite it, but to associate the first p positions of global_sample_receiver to the p elements of local_sample. Do you think this is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you overwrite `global_sample_receiver` (which is a pointer) with `local_sample` (which is an other pointer) on rank zero.

If you want to set the first `comm_sz` elements of `global_sample_receiver` with the first `comm_sz` elements from `local_sample`, then you have to copy the data (e.g. **not** the pointer) manually.

```
memcpy(global_sample_receiver, local_sample, comm_sz * sizeof(int));
```

That being said, the natural MPI way of doing this is via `MPI_Gather()`.

Here is what step 3 would look like :

```
// Step 3. Each process sends it's local sample to P0
if (my_rank == 0) {
    global_sample_receiver = (int*)malloc(pow(comm_sz,2)*sizeof(int));
}
MPI_Gather(global_sample_receiver,comm_sz, MPI_INT, local_sample, comm_sz, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```